# cannot invoke avgArray with an argument list of int

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift, and just start to learn this language by following *The Swift Programming Language*. In this book, there is an exercise question that ask me to write a function to calculate the average of an array. Here is my code:

```
func avgArray(elements: Int...)->Double{
var avg:Double = 0
var sum = 0
var count = 0
for element in elements {
    sum += element
    count += 1
}
avg = Double(sum) / Double(count)
return avg
}

let numberlist = [2,3,6,7,2,7,0,9,12]
let average = avgArray(numberlist)
```

I don't know why I can't pass the array into my function. Also, is there a way besides using a count variable to keep track of the number of elements in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know why I can't pass the array into my function.

Your `elements` is not an array, it is a variadic parameter. Change it to

```
func avgArray(elements: [Int])->Double{
```

and you should be good to go.

> is there a way besides using a count variable to keep track of the
>   number of elements in the array?

Absolutely. `count` property of the array itself. You can use it in your code like this:

```
avg = Double(sum) / Double(elements.count)
```

Comment: I have changed elements to an array, but there is another error in the code. On line `sum+=element` ---binary operator ‘+=’ can't be applied to operands of type int and array[int]

Comment: It suggests that `element` is an array now. If you changed only the one line as I suggested, it should not be the case. You can check the type(s) by alt-clicking on the variable. It should be `Int`, not `[Int]`. Xcode sometimes shows bogus errors like that. If you are certain that the types are correct, try recompiling the app or restarting Playground. If nothing helps, post your latest code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I changed it to `func avgArray(elements: [Int]...)`, which made `elements` a 2-D array. I think that is the problem

Comment: Yes, just remove the three dots.